# Sencha 2 -need help for cf json data (for eg:CFJSONReader )

Tags: coldfusion, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, coldfusion-9

I am new to sencha, and using sencha 2 mvc. I have a cfc returned json data, which I want to use in my list views. I have read about CFJsonReader and CFQueryReader, but both have been scripted for EXt Js 3 x. I cant see an mvc proper code for sencha 2 anywhere else. I tried many times and all in vain. Please some help suggest me/help me to solve my problem ...My output is like :

```
{"QUERY":{"COLUMNS":["CLIENTID"],"DATA":[[1013],[1010],[1016],[1017],[1013]]},"TOTALROWCOUNT":5}
```

Definition of store:

```
Ext.define('Mysample.store.clientsWithoutAgentOffers', {
     extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
     config: {
        autoLoad: true,
        model: 'BestHomePro.model.clientsModel',
        proxy: {
           type: 'ajax',
           url: '/sample/b.cfc?method=getClients',
           reader: cfReader
        }
     }
});
```

Please pls help me...

Comment: can you give your code? what have you tried so far?

Comment: @Saket Patel :This is my store Ext.define('Mysample.store.clientsWithoutAgentOffers', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
   config: {
   autoLoad: true,
        model: 'BestHomePro.model.clientsModel',
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            url: '/sample/b.cfc?method=getClients',    
         reader:cfReader} } });                                      I am using the cfqueryreader from http://cfqueryreader.riaforge.org/ .I dont know how to change this so that it works in sencha 2.

Answer (score 0):

The proper format for JSON for Sencha Touch 2 is described here:

[Sencha Docs - JSON Reader](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.data.reader.Json)

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this code to get the desired format of JSon:

```
<cfset retVal = ''>
<cfset qResult = ''>

<cfquery name="qResult">
    <!--- any query here --->
</cfquery>

<cfset thisArrayBecomesJSON = [] />

<cfloop query="qResult">
    <cfset thisArr = {
    "text"= "#qResult.id#, #qResult.description#",
    "value"= "#qResult.id#"
} />
    <cfset arrayAppend( thisArrayBecomesJSON, thisArr ) />
</cfloop>

<cfoutput>#serializeJSON( thisArrayBecomesJSON )#</cfoutput>
```

**Note:** if you want to use this JSon for SelectField, it must have to have the 'text' and 'value' elemnts in it.

You can make up a function for this. The function should take an object and return its Sencha Supported JSon. If you make up a function, please share with others.

Thanks